# Is calling template base class methods without providing template arguments undefined behavoir?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, multiple-inheritance, undefined-behavior

I am working on mutli platform code (Windows, Linux and Mac) written in C++. Today I had to find a problem, which orrured only in windows and it looks like it is a compiler problem. A class with multiple base classes calls a base class method, but a wrong value is passed as this.

I wrote a short C++ example to reproduce this issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>


class base1
{
public:
    int x;

    base1(int x):x(x) 
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p x=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, this, x);
    }

    void printx()
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p x=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, this, x);
    }

    void print()
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
        printx();
    }

};

template <class T>
class base2
{
public:
    int y;

    base2(int y):y(y) 
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p y=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, this, y);
    }

    void printy()
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p y=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, this, y);
    }

    void print()
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
        printy();
    }
};

class derived: public base1, public base2<derived>
{
public:
    int z;

    derived()
        : base1(1)
        , base2(2)
        , z(3)
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p z=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, this, z);
    }

    void printz()
    {
        printf("%s(): this=%p z=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, this, z);
    }

    void print()
    {
        printx();
        base1::printx();
        base1::print();

        printf("-----\n");

        printy();
        base2::printy();    // <--- this call does not work with vs2005
        base2::print();     // <--- and this call doesn't work, too.
        base2<derived>::printy();
        base2<derived>::print();

        printf("-----\n");

        printz();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    derived d;

    printf("-----\n");

    d.print();
}
```

The code compiles without any warnings on Windows (using vs2005 and vs2010), Linux (g++ (Gentoo 6.4.0-r1 p1.3) 6.4.0) and MacOS (Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)).

The code shall always print x=1, y=2 or z=3.

But the vs2005 compiled executable shows y=3 for the calls of base2::printy() and base2::print().

```
base1::base1(): this=0018FF3C x=1
base2<class derived>::base2(): this=0018FF40 y=2
derived::derived(): this=0018FF3C z=3
-----
base1::printx(): this=0018FF3C x=1
base1::printx(): this=0018FF3C x=1
base1::print(): this=0018FF3C
base1::printx(): this=0018FF3C x=1
-----
base2<class derived>::printy(): this=0018FF40 y=2
base2<class derived>::printy(): this=0018FF44 y=3 <--------
base2<class derived>::print(): this=0018FF44
base2<class derived>::printy(): this=0018FF44 y=3 <--------
base2<class derived>::printy(): this=0018FF40 y=2
base2<class derived>::print(): this=0018FF40
base2<class derived>::printy(): this=0018FF40 y=2
-----
derived::printz(): this=0018FF3C z=3
```

The call works as expected, when base2 is a regular class instead of a class template.

Since base2 is a class template, the complete name of the base class is not base2 but base2<derived>. But never the less, no compiler complains about the missing template argument, but vs2005 silently generates code passing a bad this pointer to the called method.

### So, here is my question:

Is this 'just' a compiler bug in vs2005 or is this undefined behavior, that no compiler complains about?

Comment: the thing is you cannot call a method of `base2` because there is nothing to call. Templates dont do anything unless the compiler creates an instantiation (eg `base2<derived>`). Wouldnt be the first time that someone found a quirk in VS ;)

Comment: The code looks OK to me. VS2005 is ancient, it's not really surprising it would have bugs. The code works as expected with VS2017